# Remove the directory name out of the URL in a static express app

Tags: angularjs, express

I have a very simple express setup that is serving up my static files.  My static files (it's an angular app) is running out of the `/src` folder.

Here's my express setup:

```
var express = require('express');
var fs = require('fs');
var BASE_PORT = 8080;
var ROOT_DIR = __dirname + '/';
ROOT_DIR = fs.realpathSync(ROOT_DIR);
if (!fs.existsSync(ROOT_DIR)) {
        console.log('Error: cannot find working directory: ' + ROOT_DIR);
        exit();
}


var app = express();

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
        console.log('%s %s', req.method, req.url);
        next();
});

app.use(express.static(ROOT_DIR + '/'));

app.listen((process.env.EXPRESS_PORT || 8888), function() {
        console.log('Node server started @ http://localhost:' + BASE_PORT);
        console.log('Serving static files from ' + ROOT_DIR);
        console.log('Press Ctrl + c for server termination');
});
```

My url is the app is `mydomain.com/src/#/app/files`

How can I remove that '/src' out of the url without renaming the folder?